# http 403.4 error when using https

Tags: ssl, asp-classic, https, iis-6

I'm getting the http error 403.4 - Forbidden: SSL is required to view the resource error using IIS6, even though the url starts with https.

It's a classic asp site, that used to work until the path to the files was changed. The path had to be changed because the site had to be upgraded. After getting the error; putting back the original path doesn't either.

Does anyone have any idea what I should check to resolve the above mentioned error?

Comment: Sounds like your cert isn't correctly installed. Telling the browser to use SSL (https) won't matter unless the site is actively bound to a cert, and listening for SSL requests.  In IIS, have you checked your directory security tab to ensure that your cert is installed correctly?

Comment: Is it possible to get screwed up if you change the location of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following [Configuring SSL on a Web Server or Web Site (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/56bdf977-14f8-4867-9c51-34c346d48b04.mspx?mfr=true) from Microsoft. It specifically mentions the error you get:

> If you set your Web site to require
>   SSL, as in step 6 above, and you have
>   not completed setting up SSL for the
>   site, then users browsing your site
>   will receive this error: "HTTP Error
>   403.4 - Forbidden: SSL is required to view this resource." To avoid this
>   condition, either complete all the
>   steps in the list above, or go back
>   and clear the Require Secure Channel
>   (SSL) check box (see step 6).

Comment: After some head scratching, I found out that it was the ISA firewall that was providing the SSL not IIS6. So the techs fixed it. Go figure